# how to hide NSScrollView Scroller?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, hide, nsscrollview

i am creating all the scrollviews on runtime and i want to hide NSScrollView scrollers i am not saying [self setHasVerticalScroller:NO]; however

> ```
> [self setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
> [[self verticalScroller] setHidden:YES];
> ```

does not work but there is a option on interface builder if you put scroller on design time. check out the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way:

```
NSScrollView *yourTableContainer=....
[yourTableContainer setHasVerticalScroller:NO];
[yourTableContainer setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
```